# Time synchronisation on Android devices

Tags: android, date, time, synchronization

I have 100+ `android` devices on a network. These devices constantly loosing time (time is not accurate +- few hours or sets to default date time `2010 ... 00:00` ) and I would like to synchronise time and date with android `NTP`. I can't root those devices. These devices are on a network without internet. I believe only one solution is to create exception in our firewall to allow devices to connect to android `NTP` server??? How can I find this `URL`. Is it another option so `sync` date time?

Answer (score 2):

To get internet time by following code snippet:

```
public long getInternetTime() {
    SntpClient client = new SntpClient();
    if (client.requestTime("time.nist.gov", 10000)) {
        long time = client.getNtpTime();
        return time;
    }
    else {
        Log.e(TAG, "get internet time failed");
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I'm not a Android developer. I need to sync time with internet time (default android NTP) but i can't see witch server is in use. Because my device is't rooted

Comment: Did you must use default android ntp server?

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381005/is-android-using-ntp-to-sync-time

Comment: I can't root my devices so yes I have to use default NTP

Comment: In my answer,you can use ntp without need root your device